# How To Bind A Dictionary To A ComboBox In WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dictionary, combobox

I am looking for a way to bind a Dictionary to a ComboBox

such that when I update dictionary the combobox, it will reflect the change automatically back to UI.

Now I can only populate combobox but once I update the dictionary nothing reflect to combobox.

```
Dictionary<String,String> menuItems = new Dictionary<String,String>(){{"1","one"},{"2","two"}};
combo.DataSource = new BindingSource(menuItems, null);
combo.DisplayMember = "Value";
combo.ValueMember = "Key";
menuItems.Add("ok", "success"); // combobox doesn't get updated
```

==Update==

Currently I have a workaround by calling `combo.DataSource = new BindingSource(menuItems, null);` to refresh my UI.

Answer (score 7):

`Dictionary` doesn't really have properties `Key` and `Value`. Use `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` instead. Also, you need to call `ResetBindings()` for it to work. See below:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //menuItems = new Dictionary<String, String>() { { "1", "one" }, { "2", "two" } };
        menuItems = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>() { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1","one"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2","two") };

        bs = new BindingSource(menuItems, null);

        comboBox1.DataSource = bs;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //menuItems.Add("3","three");
        menuItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3", "three"));
        bs.ResetBindings(false);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is really close to my work around. I keep calling `combo.DataSource = new BindingSource(menuItems, null);` to refresh my UI. But I still like mine because using dictionary give me an easy way to check for a duplicate key without having to call #contains.

Comment: The way to say 'thanks' here is to up vote an answer...:O)

Comment: The properties it's accessing are on each item in the collection, so the `KeyValuePair`s, which *do* have the `Key` and `Value` properties. Other than that, great answer. +1